# how to pack mix of (up to 4) uint_8t and int8_t into one uint32_t?

Tags: c++, macros, avr-gcc

**How to write set of macros to pack mix of signed and unsigned byte values (max 4 of them) to one 32-bit variable**

---

**Motivation:**

I have (third party) library, which offers function with `uint32_t` agument, which defacto contains 1-4 bytes, each of them can be signed ot unsigned, depending on some other circumstates. Internally it is decomposed to `4 bytes`, then transmited somewhere elese, where the bytes are read and interpreted as `signed` or `unsigned` and used.

I have a lot of code, which would call this function, but it could be more readable, if I could write some simple macro/macros to pack the right number of values into one and call that function in one line.

the prototype of the function is:

```
void get_data(int addr,uint32_t cmd,uint8_t cmdlen,uint8_t *data,uint8_t max_len)
```

and I would like to have shortcuts like this:

```
#define GET_DATA1(cmd1,var,len) get_data(this->i2c,PACK1(cmd1),(uint8_t *)&(var),len)
#define GET_DATA2(cmd1,cmd2,var,len) get_data(this->i2c,PACK2(cmd1,cmd2),(uint8_t *)&(var),len)
#define GET_DATA3(cmd1,cmd2,cmd3,var,len) get_data(this->i2c,PACK3(cmd1,cmd2,cmd3),(uint8_t *)&(var),len)
#define GET_DATA4(cmd1,cmd2,cmd3,cmd4,var,len) get_data(this->i2c,PACK4(cmd1,cmd2,cmd3,cmd4),(uint8_t *)&(var),len)
```

to call it as follows:

```
uint8_t status
uint8_t item=130;
char name[5];
int8_t speed = -20;

GET_DATA1(READ_STATUS,status,1); // reads 1 byte status
GET_DATA2(READ_ITEM_NAME,item,name,5); // read 5 chars long name of item 130
GET_DATA3(SET_SPEED_LIMIT,30,status,1); // set maximum speed to 30 (globally) and read 1 byte status
GET_DATA4(SET_ITEM_SPEED,item,speed,status,1); // set speed of unit 130 to -20 (reversal) and read 1 byte status
// and so on for different combination of values and commands and such
```

where the `PACKx` macros are now like that:

```
#define PACK1(cmd1) (cmd1),1
#define PACK2(cmd1,cmd2) ((cmd1<<8)|cmd2),2
#define PACK3(cmd1,cmd2,cmd3) ((cmd1<<16)|(cmd2<<8)|cmd3),3
#define PACK4(cmd1,cmd2,cmd3,cmd4) ((cmd1<<24)|(cmd2<<16)|(cmd3<<8)|cmd4),4
```

but it does not work as I want.

1) it takes only last 2 params (probabelly because some casting to 16bits variable somewhere)

2) it works wrong for signed variables (maybe making them longer somewhere along the way)

I get lots of warnings like this one:

```
PACK.ino:5:55: warning: left shift count >= width of type
#define PACK4(cmd1,cmd2,cmd3,cmd4) ((cmd1<<24)|(cmd2<<16)|(cmd3<<8)|cmd4)
```

---

**Example code:**

```
#define PACK1(cmd1) (cmd1)
#define PACK2(cmd1,cmd2) ((cmd1<<8)|cmd2)
#define PACK3(cmd1,cmd2,cmd3) ((cmd1<<16)|(cmd2<<8)|cmd3)
#define PACK4(cmd1,cmd2,cmd3,cmd4) ((cmd1<<24)|(cmd2<<16)|(cmd3<<8)|cmd4)

#define ww(a) Serial.write(a);
#define pp(a,b) Serial.print(a,b);

void hh(uint32_t x){
    uint8_t v;
    ww("     ( 0x");
    for (int i=3;i>=0;i--) { v= (x>>(8*i))& 0xFF;if(v<16) ww("0");pp(v,HEX);};
    ww(" )");
}
#define TEST1(cmd1)         ww("\r\n"); ww(" 0x");pp(cmd1,HEX); ww(" = 0x");pp(PACK1(cmd1),HEX);    cmd=PACK1(cmd1);    ww(" => 0x");pp(cmd,HEX);   hh(cmd);
#define TEST2(cmd1,cmd2)        ww("\r\n"); ww(" 0x");pp(cmd1,HEX);ww(" 0x");pp(cmd2,HEX);  ww(" = 0x");pp(PACK2(cmd1,cmd2),HEX);   cmd=PACK2(cmd1,cmd2);   ww(" => 0x");pp(cmd,HEX);   hh(cmd);
#define TEST3(cmd1,cmd2,cmd3)       ww("\r\n"); ww(" 0x");pp(cmd1,HEX);ww(" 0x");pp(cmd2,HEX);ww(" 0x");pp(cmd3,HEX);   ww(" = 0x");pp(PACK3(cmd1,cmd2,cmd3),HEX);  cmd=PACK3(cmd1,cmd2,cmd3);  ww(" => 0x");pp(cmd,HEX);   hh(cmd);
#define TEST4(cmd1,cmd2,cmd3,cmd4)  ww("\r\n"); ww(" 0x");pp(cmd1,HEX);ww(" 0x");pp(cmd2,HEX);ww(" 0x");pp(cmd3,HEX); ww(" 0x");pp(cmd4,HEX);   ww(" = 0x");pp(PACK4(cmd1,cmd2,cmd3,cmd4),HEX); cmd=PACK4(cmd1,cmd2,cmd3,cmd4); ww(" => 0x");pp(cmd,HEX);   hh(cmd);

uint32_t cmd;

uint8_t u1,u2,u3,u4;
int8_t i1,i2,i3,i4;


void setup()
{
    Serial.begin(115200);           // start serial for output
    u1=0x12;
    u2=0x34;
    u3=0x56;
    u4=0x78;

    i1=1;
    i2=-1;
    i3=8;
    i4=-8;

    TEST1(u1)
    TEST2(u1,u2)
    TEST3(u1,u2,u3)
    TEST4(u1,u2,u3,u4)
    ww("\r\n=========================================================");
    TEST1(i1)
    TEST2(i1,i2)
    TEST3(i1,i2,i3)
    TEST4(i1,i2,i3,i4)
    ww("\r\n=========================================================");
    TEST4(u1,u2,u3,u4)
    TEST4(u1,u2,u3,u4)
    TEST4(u1,u2,u3,u4)
    TEST4(u1,u2,u3,u4)
    ww("\r\n=========================================================");
    TEST4(i1,u2,u3,u4)
    TEST4(u1,i2,u3,u4)
    TEST4(u1,u2,i3,u4)
    TEST4(u1,u2,u3,i4)
    ww("\r\n=========================================================");
    TEST4(i2,u2,u3,u4)
    TEST4(u1,i2,u3,u4)
    TEST4(u1,u2,i2,u4)
    TEST4(u1,u2,u3,i2)

}
void loop()
{
}
```

---

**Result (bad):**

```
 0x12 = 0x12 => 0x12     ( 0x00000012 )
 0x12 0x34 = 0x1234 => 0x1234    ( 0x00001234 )
 0x12 0x34 0x56 = 0x3456 => 0x3456       ( 0x00003456 )
 0x12 0x34 0x56 0x78 = 0x5678 => 0x5678  ( 0x00005678 )
=========================================================
 0x1 = 0x1 => 0x1        ( 0x00000001 )
 0x1 0xFFFFFFFF = 0xFFFFFFFF => 0xFFFFFFFF       ( 0xFFFFFFFF )
 0x1 0xFFFFFFFF 0x8 = 0xFFFFFF08 => 0xFFFFFF08   ( 0xFFFFFF08 )
 0x1 0xFFFFFFFF 0x8 0xFFFFFFF8 = 0xFFFFFFF8 => 0xFFFFFFF8        ( 0xFFFFFFF8 )
=========================================================
 0x12 0x34 0x56 0x78 = 0x5678 => 0x5678  ( 0x00005678 )
 0x12 0x34 0x56 0x78 = 0x5678 => 0x5678  ( 0x00005678 )
 0x12 0x34 0x56 0x78 = 0x5678 => 0x5678  ( 0x00005678 )
 0x12 0x34 0x56 0x78 = 0x5678 => 0x5678  ( 0x00005678 )
=========================================================
 0x1 0x34 0x56 0x78 = 0x5678 => 0x5678   ( 0x00005678 )
 0x12 0xFFFFFFFF 0x56 0x78 = 0x5678 => 0x5678    ( 0x00005678 )
 0x12 0x34 0x8 0x78 = 0x878 => 0x878     ( 0x00000878 )
 0x12 0x34 0x56 0xFFFFFFF8 = 0xFFFFFFF8 => 0xFFFFFFF8    ( 0xFFFFFFF8 )
=========================================================
 0xFFFFFFFF 0x34 0x56 0x78 = 0x5678 => 0x5678    ( 0x00005678 )
 0x12 0xFFFFFFFF 0x56 0x78 = 0x5678 => 0x5678    ( 0x00005678 )
 0x12 0x34 0xFFFFFFFF 0x78 = 0xFFFFFF78 => 0xFFFFFF78    ( 0xFFFFFF78 )
 0x12 0x34 0x56 0xFFFFFFFF = 0xFFFFFFFF => 0xFFFFFFFF    ( 0xFFFFFFFF )
```

---

**Problems (again):**

1) it takes only last 2 params (probabelly because some casting to 16bits variable somewhere)

2) it works wrong for signed variables (maybe making them longer somewhere along the way)

Comment: Is the byte order persistent? If so, you could probably use a union instead of the current packing... Another question - are you limited from using named arguments (using an argument struct and a variadic macro)?

Comment: Another thought - using bit-shifting on `uint8_t` probably overflows the limit of the type, resulting in 0.

Comment: the library function get_data takes `cmd` parameter and `cmdlen` which says, how much low bbytes of CMD is send in order from the most significant down. In the first section of `TEST`s the `0x12` is `cmd1` and is send `first` everytime, and it keeps information, what the rest means like `READ_ITEM_NAME` marks, that `item number` would be send and the othe side is the supposed to reply with `5` bytes of `name`. So the cmd1 may be bits 0..7 or 8..15 or 16..23 or 24..31 depending on `cmdlen` and so the number of `cmdxxx` commands.

Comment: I do not know, what  `variadic macro` is (i will google it now), the prototype of `get_data` is out of my reach, so I cannont change it and is written with the names.

Comment: You can see an example of a `variadic macro` in the answer I posted. Good luck with it all!

Comment: `variadic macro` works for me (just tested it), but I would like somehow pop the arguments from it too (would help me in other problems I currently solve also), hope that is possible at MACROs level

Comment: I'm happy this works for you. However, I'm not sure I understand what you mean by "pop" the arguments... but you can definitely control everything within the inline function implementation. Remember that unspecified arguments are initialized to `0` (or `NULL`)... but 0 and NULL might be valid values as well. I'n my example `.arg3` is initialized to 0 since I don't specify it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the problem was on bad types (as was pointed out) and could be solved by explicitelly casting all arguments to 8-bit unsigned (to preserve value and do not expand sign) and then casting the shift to long enough type.

This one works for me (the example code compiles without warnings and yelds correct results) (as Lundin pointed out the casts should be organized a little different way, so I fixed `SHIFT_IT`. Still yelds the same good result):

```
#define SHIFT_IT(cmd,bits) (((uint32_t)(uint8_t)cmd)<<bits)

#define PACK1(cmd1) (SHIFT_IT(cmd1,0))
#define PACK2(cmd1,cmd2) (SHIFT_IT(cmd1,8)|SHIFT_IT(cmd2,0))
#define PACK3(cmd1,cmd2,cmd3) (SHIFT_IT(cmd1,16)|SHIFT_IT(cmd2,8)|SHIFT_IT(cmd3,0))
#define PACK4(cmd1,cmd2,cmd3,cmd4) (SHIFT_IT(cmd1,24)|SHIFT_IT(cmd2,16)|SHIFT_IT(cmd3,8)|SHIFT_IT(cmd4,0))
```

---

**Result (good)**:

```
 0x12 = 0x12 => 0x12     ( 0x00000012 )
 0x12 0x34 = 0x1234 => 0x1234    ( 0x00001234 )
 0x12 0x34 0x56 = 0x123456 => 0x123456   ( 0x00123456 )
 0x12 0x34 0x56 0x78 = 0x12345678 => 0x12345678  ( 0x12345678 )
=========================================================
 0x1 = 0x1 => 0x1        ( 0x00000001 )
 0x1 0xFFFFFFFF = 0x1FF => 0x1FF         ( 0x000001FF )
 0x1 0xFFFFFFFF 0x8 = 0x1FF08 => 0x1FF08         ( 0x0001FF08 )
 0x1 0xFFFFFFFF 0x8 0xFFFFFFF8 = 0x1FF08F8 => 0x1FF08F8  ( 0x01FF08F8 )
=========================================================
 0x12 0x34 0x56 0x78 = 0x12345678 => 0x12345678  ( 0x12345678 )
 0x12 0x34 0x56 0x78 = 0x12345678 => 0x12345678  ( 0x12345678 )
 0x12 0x34 0x56 0x78 = 0x12345678 => 0x12345678  ( 0x12345678 )
 0x12 0x34 0x56 0x78 = 0x12345678 => 0x12345678  ( 0x12345678 )
=========================================================
 0x1 0x34 0x56 0x78 = 0x1345678 => 0x1345678     ( 0x01345678 )
 0x12 0xFFFFFFFF 0x56 0x78 = 0x12FF5678 => 0x12FF5678    ( 0x12FF5678 )
 0x12 0x34 0x8 0x78 = 0x12340878 => 0x12340878   ( 0x12340878 )
 0x12 0x34 0x56 0xFFFFFFF8 = 0x123456F8 => 0x123456F8    ( 0x123456F8 )
=========================================================
 0xFFFFFFFF 0x34 0x56 0x78 = 0xFF345678 => 0xFF345678    ( 0xFF345678 )
 0x12 0xFFFFFFFF 0x56 0x78 = 0x12FF5678 => 0x12FF5678    ( 0x12FF5678 )
 0x12 0x34 0xFFFFFFFF 0x78 = 0x1234FF78 => 0x1234FF78    ( 0x1234FF78 )
 0x12 0x34 0x56 0xFFFFFFFF = 0x123456FF => 0x123456FF    ( 0x123456FF )
=========================================================
 0xFFFFFFFF 0x34 0x56 0x78 = 0xFF345678 => 0xFF345678    ( 0xFF345678 )
 0x12 0xFFFFFFFF 0x56 0x78 = 0x12FF5678 => 0x12FF5678    ( 0x12FF5678 )
 0x12 0x34 0xFFFFFFFF 0x78 = 0x1234FF78 => 0x1234FF78    ( 0x1234FF78 )
 0x12 0x34 0x56 0xFFFFFFFF = 0x123456FF => 0x123456FF    ( 0x123456FF )
=========================================================
 0xFFFFFFFF 0x34 0x56 0x78 = 0xFF345678 => 0xFF345678    ( 0xFF345678 )
 0x12 0xFFFFFFFF 0x56 0x78 = 0x12FF5678 => 0x12FF5678    ( 0x12FF5678 )
 0x12 0x34 0xFFFFFFFF 0x78 = 0x1234FF78 => 0x1234FF78    ( 0x1234FF78 )
 0x12 0x34 0x56 0xFFFFFFFF = 0x123456FF => 0x123456FF    ( 0x123456FF )
```

Anyway, if I find better way (maybe with variadic macros, to have just one  PACK with variable number of commands) I will add it here too.

(BTW: Thanks all to help me find the way, I was really deep locked before)

Comment: You should parenthesize the macro arguments: `#define SHIFT_IT(cmd, bits) ((uint32_t)((uint8_t)(cmd)) << (bits))`

Comment: This is still not correct. Given that MSB is set in `cmd`, you invoked undefined behavior, because `cmd` will get implicitly promoted to type `int` which is signed. Correct code is: `((uint32_t)(cmd))<<(bits))`

Comment: Sorry, I tried your version and it is not correct. It yelds bad data. It looks like the compiler promote the (negative) args to 32bits with signum and then used that for shifting, and 32bit ORed it with result, which fills the whole MSB part of result with 1's. The disassembler show that too, if I read it correctly. My version changes the signed to unsigned with the same bits, then shifts it up and place it to result. Disassembled code shows, that the compiler just ORed the valiable with correct register of result (patched just 8 bits in middle).

Comment: You are doing something wrong then, or maybe your system has 64 bit int. On a fundamental level, `small_integer_type << something` is always incorrect code, because of integer promotion. You should never shift data into the sign bits of a signed integer (and you should never left shift a negative value).

Comment: It seems, that int is 16 bits. (and documentation suppost this too https://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference/Int ) Also the result of my method are as I posted in **Results (good)**, so it works as I need, while your method returns what is under **Results (bad)** in question, so it does not solve my problem. (And it would be strange, if it would work, as canging type to longer expands the sign, so for negative result is long negative and that shifted and ORed replace the high part of total result regardless of cmd1, cmd2... values).

Comment: Maybe you are trying to solve something different, than the original question (how compose mixed 8-bit values to one 32-bit value in expected order) - it is not as much about signed long integers, it is more about combining 1..4 8-bit values to one 32-bit field aligned by the last value to the LSB bit of that array.

Comment: I assumed you had 32 bit integers. Merely change the cast to `(uint16_t)` instead. I'm pointing out something which is 100% undefined behavior no matter compiler, it has nothing to do with a change of functionality. Anyway, I'll post an answer with alternative methods.

Comment: fixed casts in `SHIF_IT`, hope now it is fully defined - first cast everything to `uint8_t`, then immediately to `uint32_t` so the result does not propagate sign. Compiles to the exactly same asm code anyway :)

Comment: Seems what you are actually looking for is to mask away the sign bits: `( (uint32_t)((cmd)&0xFF) << (bits) )`.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure about the library and what's your use-case, but I can see the following error in your `PACKx` macros:

```
#define PACK3(cmd1,cmd2,cmd3) ((cmd1<<16)|(cmd2<<8)|cmd3) // ! (cmd2 << 8) == 0
```

Since the `cmd2` type is limited to 8 bits, left-shifting by eight bits (or more) will cause the original 8bit type to overflow, so the result is probably 0...

...To be more precise, the result is "undefined" (credit to @GavinPortwood in the comments)... to be even more precise, we would have to get into integer promotion details and wonder why your system promotes uint8_t into a 16 bit type instead of a 32 bit type...

...but either way, it's a good practice to manually cast the type to the number of bits required as well as to truncate the results to the number of bits wanted.

The same is true for `cmd3`.

You should probably also consider that bit-shifting a signed variable is inconsistent across systems, since some systems protect the signed bit from being shifted - so that `(-4 >> 1) == -2` instead of loosing the signed bit, which might give you `126` (if my math is right).

My last pointer is that I would avoid having a long list of macros when possible.

I think wrapping the library would probably be a better choice and it will make maintenance far easier.

Having said that, here's my untested take on the macro solution:

```
struct GET_DATA_args {
  uint8_t cmd;
  uint8_t arg1;
  uint8_t arg2;
  uint8_t arg3;
  uint8_t argc;
  uint8_t *dest;
  uint8_t limit;
  int addr;
};

static inline void GET_DATA(struct GET_DATA_args args) {
  uint32_t cmd = args.cmd | ((uint32_t)args.arg1 << 8) |
                 ((uint32_t)args.arg2 << 16) | ((uint32_t)args.arg3 << 24);
  if (!args.limit) /* use 1 as a default value. */
    args.limit = 1;
  get_data(args.addr, cmd, args.argc + 1, args.dest, args.limit);
}

#define GET_DATA(...)                                                          \
  GET_DATA((struct GET_DATA_args){.addr = this->i2c, __VA_ARGS__})
```

You can use it like this:

```
GET_DATA(.argc = 2, .cmd = SET_SPEED_LIMIT,
         .arg1 = 30, .arg2 = status,
         .dest = &status /*, .limit = 1 - by default */);
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure doing a shift equal length of the type is undefined behavior and not 0.

Comment: @GavinPortwood - Technically you're right. However, the standard states that "The type of the result is that of the promoted left operand" ... my experience shows you'd simply get 0 and hopefully a compiler warning.

Comment: anyway it resulted to 0 in my case everytime. And I know, that it is not working, but at least I tried to show the idea behind that.

Comment: It is nice trick with the structure, to use named parameters like python does :) I will use it some day for sure. But I would here have the code as compact as possible, without the names, if I can avoid it here. As last instance I can do macros to assing all the unused args with zero or so, and sort it out inside the function.

Comment: @gilhad , I'm happy you enjoyed the tip :-) ... I'm sure you can simply fix the code you already have instead of using the variadic macro approach... however, I hope you will consider that we spend at least 10X as much on reading and debugging code as we do on actually writing anything... Personally, I find that it's worth spending the extra minute while writing than having to spend an extra ten decoding my own code when I need to perform any maintenance.

Comment: @Myst Not only technically, I've seen this exact thing (shift past end) cause trouble when changing compiler flags. Not to mention compilers or compiler versions. It's a poor choice to rely on what your compiler seems to implement all the times you've checked. It would be better to implement an inline function which has the behavior you want

Comment: *Since the cmd2 type is limited to 8 bits, left-shifting by eight bits (or more) will cause the type to overflow,*: not at all, `cmd2` is promoted to `int` before the shift operation. Conversely, if type `int` is 16 bits, shifting by 15 or more has undefined behavior. Also the macro arguments should be parenthesized: `#define PACK3(cmd1, cmd2, cmd3)  (((cmd1) << 16) | ((cmd2) << 8) | (cmd3))`

Comment: @GavinPortwood - I heartily agree. Perhaps the word "technically" was not the best choice of words, as I meant it in a positive sense (as in, "when you go deeply into the subject matter").

Comment: @chqrlie - although the returned result **should** be promoted (how many bits in an `int`? on which system? which promoting rules? C11 changed some promotion rules), experience shows that this should be avoided. Different systems, different compilers and even the same compiler on the same system with different flags all behave differently. It's better to promote the type manually than to trust the system to provide enough bits, The perfect example is the OPs system that seems to use 16bit int promotion for some obscure reason. I think it's clearer this way than explaining too much.

Comment: @chqrlie - P.S. I updated the answer to reflect your comment. I didn't add any details and I left the abstraction, but I pointed out that there's more to be learned... I believe that sometimes too many details get in the way of the learning process.

Comment: I think, the obscure reason for 16 bits is avr-gcc (as is in the tags from begin) compiling for avr8 platform, where int is (IMHO) 16 bits. Anyway I learn a lot from this problem and your comments :)

Answer (score 1):

What you probably *should* do is to write a function, to make the code type safe and generic. Depending on byte order (endianess) etc, this function might look a bit different. Something along the lines of:

```
#include <stdint.h>
#include <string.h>

uint32_t pack (size_t size, uint8_t bytes[size])
{
  uint8_t tmp[sizeof(uint32_t)] = {0};
  memcpy(tmp, bytes, size);

  return tmp[0] <<  0 |
         tmp[1] <<  8 |
         tmp[2] << 16 |
         tmp[3] << 24 ; 
}
```

Macros are hard to read, understand and maintain, so I wouldn't recommend them. But if you insist on using them, you *could* do some evil macro-magic with variadic macros:

(assuming 32 bit CPU)

```
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <inttypes.h>

#define SHIFT(cmd, bits) (((uint32_t)(cmd)) << (bits))

#define PACK1(c1,...)          ( SHIFT(c1, 0) )
#define PACK2(c1,c2,...)       ( SHIFT(c1, 8) | SHIFT(c2, 0) )
#define PACK3(c1,c2,c3,...)    ( SHIFT(c1,16) | SHIFT(c2, 8) | SHIFT(c3,0) )
#define PACK4(c1,c2,c3,c4,...) ( SHIFT(c1,24) | SHIFT(c2,16) | SHIFT(c3,8) | SHIFT(c4,0) )

#define PACK_VARIABLE(c1,c2,c3,c4,N,...) PACK##N (c1, c2, c3, c4, __VA_ARGS__)
#define PACK(...) PACK_VARIABLE(__VA_ARGS__,4,3,2,1,0)

int main (void)
{
  printf("%" PRIX32 "\n", PACK(0xAA));
  printf("%" PRIX32 "\n", PACK(0xAA, 0xBB));
  printf("%" PRIX32 "\n", PACK(0xAA, 0xBB, 0xCC));
  printf("%" PRIX32 "\n", PACK(0xAA, 0xBB, 0xCC, 0xDD)); 
  return 0;  
}
```

Output:

```
AA
AABB
AABBCC
AABBCCDD
```

Comment: Still the same problem - if last arg (say c4) is variable declared as `signed` and its value is negative (say `-1`), then the result of PACK is also negative (`-1` in this case) regardless of other aguments. The CPU is 8-bit anyway as it is Arduino (AVR328 to be precise). The function does not compile, throwing error `PACK.ino:2:47: error: use of parameter outside function body before ‘]’ token
 uint32_t pack (size_t size, uint8_t bytes[size])
` as the `size` is parameter and cannot be used in the header of the  function. Also shifting byte 16 of 24 bits left does not work with 16-bites ints

Comment: @gilhad It is up to the caller to ensure that their 8 bit parameter is 8 bit. Simply mask it (`c4 & 0xFF`) before passing it on. Regarding the error, you have to compile C code with a _standard compliant C compiler_. Arduino uses a non-standard C++ compiler, I believe? That's something else entirely. The size parameter can be used just fine, do you know what a VLA is? The function is using a VLA and C++ does not yet support VLAs.

Comment: here is command line, which compiles the code and throws errors `/usr/bin/avr-g++ -x c++ -include Arduino.h -MMD -c -mmcu=atmega328p -DF_CPU=16000000L -DARDUINO=181 -DARDUINO_ARCH_AVR -D__PROG_TYPES_COMPAT__ -I/home/gilhad/GIT/PROJECTS/arduino.HB3/Arduino/hardware/arduino/avr/cores/arduino -I/home/gilhad/GIT/PROJECTS/arduino.HB3/Arduino/hardware/arduino/avr/variants/eightanaloginputs    -Wall -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -Os -pedantic -Wall -Wextra -fdiagnostics-color -fno-exceptions -std=gnu++11 PACK.ino -o /home/gilhad/GIT/PROJECTS/arduino.HB3/HB3//bin/xx/pro.16MHzatmega328/PACK.o
`

Comment: @gilhad g++ is a C++ compiler. It can't compile modern C code. You tagged your question as C.

Comment: Sorry, I did not realize that. I found some tutorials on web, try that and it worked, I do not understand fully the backgrounds and learn when I hit wall ocassionally. I will remove the tag just now, as it should not be there in this case. what is the rigth tag? C++ or C++11 ? I think C++ from th `-x c++` part